# MPI_MAXLOC for an array of double values

Tags: c, mpi

What is the data structure used to store the return value of MPI_MAXLOC in MPI_Reduce() function  for an array of **double** values

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There is an example of use of MPI_MAXLOC in c in the [mpi standards, on page 181](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf). Could you please describe your problem in a more specific way, by providing what you have tried, or a piece of code showing the structure that is to be reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `C`, the MPI type you must use is `MPI_DOUBLE_INT`, and there is no predefined C structure for that (e.g you have to create it manually) like this

```
struct { 
    double val; 
    int   rank; 
};
```

fwiw, the predefined `MPI_DOUBLE_INT` datatype is defined like this

```
type[0] = MPI_DOUBLE
type[1] = MPI_INT 
disp[0] = 0 
disp[1] = sizeof(double) 
block[0] = 1 
block[1] = 1 
MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2, block, disp, type, MPI_DOUBLE_INT)
```

note that in `Fortran`, you have to use `MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION` (and yes, the index is a double precision in Fortran !)

this is explained in http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node114.htm#Node114 and there is even an example with double for both `C` and `Fortran`